# Display a list of matrices without row and column names

Tags: r, matrix, lapply, names, write.table

I want to display a list of matrices (not a single matrix, as has been asked about elsewhere) without the small [1,] and [,1] row and column indicators.

For example, given `myList`:

```
myList <- list(matrix(c(1,2,3,4,5,6), nrow = 2), matrix(c(1,2,3,4,5,6), nrow = 3))
names(myList) <- c("This is the first matrix:", "This is the second matrix:")
```

I'm looking for some function `myFunction()` that will output:

```
> myFunction(myList)
$`This is the first matrix:`
 1    3    5
 2    4    6

$`This is the second matrix:`
 1    4
 2    5
 3    6
```

It would be even better if it could eliminate the $`...` around the list names so that it would display:

```
This is the first matrix:
 1    3    5
 2    4    6

This is the second matrix:
 1    4
 2    5
 3    6
```

After reading all the related questions, I've tried

```
 myList %>% lapply(print, row.names = F)
 myList %>% lapply(prmatrix, collab = NULL, rowlab = NULL)
 myList %>% lapply(write.table, sep = " ",  row.names = F, col.names = F)
```

But none work as intended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you are just missing the headers? How about something like

```
library(purrr) #for walk2()
print_with_name <- function(mat, name) {
  cat(name,"\n")
  write.table(mat, sep = " ",  row.names = F, col.names = F)
}
myList %>% walk2(., names(.), print_with_name)
```